# Add some text to particular area in UITextView programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, cgrect

I create an instance of `UITextView` programmatically. I want to add some text to particular area in `UITextView` programmatically. Here is my code to create `UITextView`.

```
      UITextView *textView =[[UITextView alloc]init];
      textView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,282,210);
      [textView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
      [self.view addSubview:textView];
```

For example I want to add some text to particular Area `CGRectMake(260,190,20,20)`.
Then add this text to `UITextView`.
Programmatically, please any one guide me, how is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an `UILabel` there.

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
TextView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,282.0,210.0);
[textView setReturnKeyType: UIReturnKeyDone];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.frame = CGRectMake(260.0,190.0,20.0,20.0);
label.text = @"T"; //here you set the text you want...

[textView.view addSubview: label];

[self.view addSubview: textView];
```

Comment: In that case you have to keep the reference to your label. You can simply set it's frame again and it will move. You're gonna have to calculate the width of the text manually - i think there are several questions (with answers) on this topic here on SO, so you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: You're welcome. I think you could work on this one. If there will be more of this UITextViews with labels added in your app you might consider sublassing UITextView.

Comment: Thanx Dear.offcourse your post solve my basic problem.now i will search to make it better.

Comment: Dear if you free please Check my Second question my be you Suggest better Solution for me.which is related with nsmutablearray data attached with E-mail.please Check my profil..